# Beginning Java Interface Program Collecting Strings and Printing

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, subclass

I am trying to write a program that reads all words from user inputted scanner, puts them into an ArrayList calls a method,  and prints a list of all the words that have a length of less than five.  Yes, I can write this in a single program but the purpose of the assignment is to work with interfaces and inheritance.  I wrote a program that loops user input into an array of objects.  I wrote an interface (this cannot be changed), and i implemented a class which scans the words from the array and gives a boolean value depending on whether the word is less than five or more than five letters.  I wrote a method that takes the answer from the class and creates a new ArrayList of objects.  If the word is less than five letters then it is added to the array.  I am trying to call the method into my main but i am getting a "Filters is abstract" " Cannot be instantiated" error...but my interface is not abstract?  I have no idea how to fix it and its driving me crazy....Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you!

```
public interface Filters
{
    boolean accept(Object x);
//this interface cannot be changed.
}

public class SWordFilter implements Filters
{
//This is my subclass for the interface
    public boolean accept(Object x)
    {
    String y =(String) x;
    boolean accept=false;

    if (y.length()< 5)
    accept=true;
    return accept;
    }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyHomework
{
 //this is my main and my method.  I cannot call the method.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<Object> names=new ArrayList<Object>();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        int i=0;
        while(i<5)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the words");
            names.add(in.next());
            i++;
        }
        Filters tran= new Filters(names);
        Object result=collectAll(names,tran);
    }


public static ArrayList<Object> collectAll (ArrayList<Object> list, Filters f)

{
    ArrayList<Object> result= new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        if (f.accept(list.get(x)))
        {
            result.add(list.get(x));
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.print("the word is too long");
        }
        //SWordFilter julie= new SWordFilter();
        //System.out.print(julie.accept(names.get(j)));
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
Filters tran= new Filters(names);
```

As `Filters` is an interface, and *interfaces* and *abstract* classes can't be instantiate, you can only declare it( allocate it) for obtaining memory for the object.

All the member function (methods) are abstract, but you can assign it to a new object of one of the classes that implemented this interface:

```
Filters tran = new SWordFilter();
```

Understand the interfaces like this:

You have some classes need to have a base class, like `java.util.List` is the base class of both `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.LinkedList`, you can't instantiate `List` but you can assign it to *ArrayList* or *LinkedList* as abstracts are specifically designed to not be instantiated, they holds a common behavior of some classes.

Comment: Im not sure what that means...I know the line that is causing the problem....but I dont understand the problem

Comment: Think of an interface as an abstract class where *every* method is abstract.

Comment: @azad Thank you so much for explaining the concept to me.  I understand now what is going on. Thank you!!!

Comment: @LindsayBaird: You're welcome, also look to oracle tutorial about [**What's an Interface?**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an interface (because it is abstract), instantiate your method that implements the filter instead!!